# Clipping common overlapping regions in multiple trajectories

Tags: overlay, trajectory

I have 20 trajectories
I found a method on Github https://github.com/wisaaco/MatchGPX. The method's output is shown below. There are two GPS traces one in blue and other in Red.
The overlapping portion is marked with +  and based on the continuity different regions  R1, R2- R6 have been created.  I have more than two GPS trajectories and what I want to do is identify regions similar as in the image and clip the data belonging  different trajectories
[image: overlapping with two GPS traces]

GPS accuracy : 3m

I see Vector Overlay and clipping in this tutorial  https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#id32